# Sessions issue while using two sites at the same browser

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

I used `CodeIngniter` framework to build two simple web application and add login pages according to [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/476944/Create-user-login-with-Codeigniter).

Everything is working fine. But when I use both application on the same browser, both of them were redirect to login page.

I used following code as per the article to set,check and destroy the session data in both sites,

when login,

```
$data = array(
    'userid' => 1,
    'name' => "Admin",
    'username' => "admin",
    'role' => "admin",
    'validated' => true
    );
$this->session->set_userdata($data);
```

in other pages,

```
private function check_isvalidated(){
    if(! $this->session->userdata('validated')){
        redirect('login');
    }
}
```

When logout,

```
public function logout(){
    $this->session->sess_destroy();
    redirect('login');
}
```

So I guess something I need to do in CodeIngniter sessions, but I couldn't find what I need do.

Any help would be appreciate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This happens when the 2 sites are using the same session name AND run on the same domain (localhost while developing is the common problem) either rename the sessions, or ensure both sites are on unique domains or do both.

Comment: thanks all, I set the different `$config['sess_cookie_name']` in cofig file and now its working fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When two applications are using the same session identifier it will login for both applications or for none. Because the cookies are shared browser wide. What you have to do is force codeigniter to use a different cookiename for each application, then the sessions are seperated and can you use two logins.

Comment: I set the different $config['sess_cookie_name'] in cofig file and now its working fine